# Word Mover's distance calculation between word pairs of two documents

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, wmd

According to WMD [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf), travel cost or Euclidean distance between word pairs is calculated the way shown in the figure below.

[image]

Is this distance calculated in pair wise in a specific order? Such that the first, second and so on from each document as shown in the figure Or Obama's distance is calculated from all four words in D0 and then the minimum of these four is shown in the figure only.

Can someone explain how this works?

Also, why is then all three words in D3 compared with President in D0?

Comment: I may point out that I've provided an (let's just say "alternative") answer to this question on CrossValidated, where it was also asked by OP, and which  seems like the "more correct" stack exchange for this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/303227/44585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of WMD requires finding the cheapest shifting of word-weight-configuration in a first text, into the word-weight-configuration of the second text.

The word-order is irrelevant. Any word's mass in one text could be shifted to the position of any word in the other text. The optimization process which finds the best shifts thus will consider many possible pairings. After it finds the best, the final single WMD number is the total travel distance in that best solution.

Because of differences in word count, words may not be shifted one-to-one, but as proportion of the full text's mass. So consider the bottom example in the graphic you included: the top text *D0* has 4 significant words, and the bottom text *D3* has just 3 significant words. So each of the top text's 4 words can be thought of as having 0.25 mass, and each of the bottom text's words can be thought of as having 0.33 mass.

'Obama' might thus map very closely to 'President' - but even moving 0.25 of 'Obama' mass to 'President' leaves 0.08 mass left over that must travel to another *D0* word. Similarly with 'Illinois' and 'Chicago' – even if a 0.25 of 'Illinois' mass is moved to 'Chicago', 0.08 is left-over that must travel to another *D0* word. The exact mix of paths and proportions chosen will be the best possible, but will typically involve some words being fractionally shifted across multiple other words.

Comment: Ahh okay. If the significant words are the same in both texts then it should be a simple algorithm to find the minimum distance between various word pairing and pick the ones with minimum distance and the sum it up.

Comment: wouldn't the best path be the shortest euclidean distance between two words from both texts if their size is the same? Let's say text1: word1 word2. text2: word3, word4. So calculate the distance from word3 to (word1, word2) and from word4 to (word1, word2). Then take the min of the two as a wm distance.

Comment: If the significant words are exactly the same between two texts, the WMD is 0.0. If the texts have the same number of words, the calculation is simpler (and every word's mass can be paired with exactly one other word's mass). Tiny contrived examples (like with two 2-word texts) may not be very illustrative of what happens in more typical comparisons. But in fact for your example, you'd calculate both possible travel-plans: candidate1 = d(w1,w3) + d(w2,w4); candidate2 = d(w1,w4) + d(w2,w3). Whichever is lower is the WMD.

Comment: (The actual optimizations from research papers, as used by the PyEMD library gensim relies upon, don't need to do a naive exhaustive check of *every* possible routing. But it still becomes more expensive as the number of words involved grows – unlike alternatives where a text can be given a single summary vector which is then quickly cosine-distance comparable, in constant time, with other same-dimensionality vectors.)